# Destroy deque using pointers and free in C

Tags: c, pointers, free, deque

I'm trying to destroy my deque but somehow I fail with pointers. I have written the following code (deque is a pointer to a pointer, which points to the first element of the deque). The DequeItem's are structs with fields next (pointer to next element) and data (void *).

```
void deque_destroy(DequeItem **deque) {
    DequeItem *temp;
    DequeItem *item;
    for (item = *deque; item != NULL; item = temp) {
        printf("%d", *((int*)((item)->data)));
        temp = item->next;
        free(item);
    }
}
```

The struct declaration is:

```
struct DequeItem {
  void *data;                  // Data stored in the deque item

  struct DequeItem *previous;  // Pointer to the previous DequeItem in the ring
  struct DequeItem *next;      // Pointer to the next DequeItem in the ring
};

typedef struct DequeItem DequeItem;
```

Comment: So what isn't working exactly?

Comment: I get a segmentation fault. In gdb: "Could not access memory. Reason: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000. So I have a null pointer, right?

Comment: And the segmentation fault happens on the first line in the for-loop, so the printf().

Comment: item is not NULL but data might be, and since you are dereferencing it you will get the BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the next-pointer of the last element (back element) in the deque will point to the first element (front element) even though the first element has been destroyed. I fixed this by setting

```
(*deque)->previous->next = NULL
```

before the for-loop above. Thanks for help!

Comment: i.e. the next-pointer of the last element was something else than NULL, when the loop reaches the last element and effectively tries to free memory at the address, which previously contained the front element.

Answer (score 3):

Looks correct, well done to read out `temp` *before* you call `free()` on the item, that's a common beginner mistake you've avoided.

I think you need to provide more information about what goes wrong, and perhaps also the struct declarations.

Is the `data` member also dynamically allocated memory? If so, you might need a `free(item->data);` call, too depending on how it was allocated when the item was created.

As commenters have pointed out, your `data` pointer might be `NULL` so you should check it before printing:

```
if(item->data != NULL)
  printf("%d\n", *(int *) item->data);
```

Note:

- [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) of the casting expression makes it easier to read.
- Include line feed (`'\n'`) in the `printf()` string to avoid buffering confusion and separating the values visually.